# Isn't $ n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1) $ a factorial already?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

Let $ m \ge 1 $ and $ n \ge 1 $ be integers

Let $A$ be a set of size $m$

Let $B$ be a set of size $n$

How many one-to-one functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ are there?

*skipped stuff*

$$
n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1) \\
= n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1) \cdot \frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)...1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)...1} \\
= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)...1} \\
= \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}
$$

My question is: Isn't $ n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1) $ already a factorial? Also isn't the $+1$ there to make it so you don't multiply against $0$ for product rule?

Also how does $$
n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1) \cdot \frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)...1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)...1} \\
= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)...1} \\
$$

Comment: No, the $+1$ is there to ensure there are $m$ terms.  As to your main question - what is your definition of "factorial" if this is a factorial?

Comment: It is only a factorial if $n=m$ or $m=n-1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I still don't understand what you mean that the $+1$ is the ensure there are m terms.

Comment: What do *you* mean by factorial? That expression is simply the (falling) [Pochhammer](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/introductions/FactorialBinomials/ShowAll.html) symbol

Comment: But $n-m+1=1$ no? So I see $n(n-1)(n-2)...1$ already.

Comment: @user1766555: $n-m+1$ is $1$ if and only if $m=n$, which certainly is not in general true. When $n=5$ and $m=2$, for instance, $n-m+1=5-2+1=4$. The argument requires that the number be the product of $m$ consecutive integers starting with $n$ and working down. If $m=1$, that one integer is $n$, which is $n-m+1=n-1+1=n$. If $m=2$, those two integers are $n$ and $n-1$, which is $n-m+1=n-2+1$. In general you’re multiplying $n-0$, $n-1$, $n-2$, ... until you’ve multiplied together $m$ integers. The numbers that you’re subtracting from $n$ are $0,1,2,\ldots$; in order to get $m$ of them, you ...

Comment: ... have to stop when you subtract $m-1$, because you started by subtracting $0$, not $1$. And $n-(m-1)=n-m+1$.

Comment: should $m=n$ since this is a bijective function?

Comment: Also how does the 2nd line go into the 3rd line?

Answer (score 0):

No, a factorial is something like $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5$. You have something like $9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$. That is, a factorial has to start from $1$ and go up - yours starts from some number and goes down (and crucially, doesn't go down all the way to $1$, otherwise it *would* be a factorial, just written backwards).

However, you can express products like that using factorials, which is what they're doing here. For example:

$$9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5=9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot\not4\cdot\not3\cdot\not2\cdot\not1=\frac {9!} {4!}$$

The $+1$ is not really there "to avoid multiplication by $0$", it's there because... well, because the formula is incorrect without it.

Comment: There is no forward or backwards.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Man, that's what I tried to tell the guy this morning when I forgot to get out of reverse and backed into his Volkswagon...

Answer (score 0):

The notation $n!$ is used to denote the product $\prod_{j=1}^n j$ and this is commonly called "$n$ factorial." Your expression is of the form $\prod_{j=n-m + 1}^n j$ and this is thus not a factorial in this sense, as it starts at $n-m+1$ and not at $1$ (except if $n=m$).

However, there is a pair of generalization of the notion of factorials [called rising and falling factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

There one has

- $(n)_m$ a *falling*  factorial defined as $n(n-1) \dots (n-m+1)$, and
- $(n)^m$ a *rising* factorial defined as $n(n+1) \dots (n+m-1)$.

The usual factorials can be recovered as the special cases $n= m$ for falling and $n=1$ for rising.

Thus, your quantity is not a factorial in the usual sense however you could conveniently express it as $(n)_m$ a falling factorial.

**For your additional question:**

The product before the fraction contains all integers from $n$ to $n+m -1$ the denominator contains all integers from $n-m$ to $1$ so taking them all together these are all the integers from $n$ to $1$, which is what is written.